# How we can change the text on the menu bar for different files

Tags: android

I have a registration form and a login form in my Android Studio project. At the moment the text at the top of each is the same, but I want different text on each page.

How can I change this so that the highlighted text on each page is different? Where do I configure this?

[image: Register form and login form]

Comment: use a custom toolbar

Comment: look i used..can you help me with pictures i will be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please clarify what it is you want to accomplish, and what your question is.

Comment: @AliRaees Are you using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an image to the toolbar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058430/add-an-image-to-the-toolbar-in-android)

Comment: @AliRaees checkout my link and answer from there it's custom Toolbar and just set a name in different Activity like Register & Login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to create a toolbar.xml file and insert it into your all activity where you want to change the name of the title bar.

This is how to create Custom toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then find the toolbar into java file and set the name to title bar like 
    this:-

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

If any query regarding this,ask happy to help.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Vishal Sharma